# Diamond dataset - how plot Price value in a Histogram(using ggplot2)?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm working on the Diamond dataset in R and trying to plot **Price** against the **Cut** in a Histogram.

Here is my code -

```
ggplot(data = diamonds,
   aes(x = cut, y = price))+
geom_histogram( stat = "identity")
```

After execution I get below histogram

[image]

If you see the Price it has been plotted as some exponential value. Whereas the max(Price) is 20000.

Can someone help me in getting the actual min to max value range of Price on the Y axis?

Thanks,
Santosh G.

Comment: A histogram shows distribution, the x-axis are bins, and the y-axis is frequency. You can't plot two of them in histogram? It is bar graph you want to plot? Just use `geom_col()` instead

Comment: cut has multiple price values. How do you expect the plot to look like? A histogram for each cut value? Something like this would be informative `ggplot(data = diamonds, aes(price, fill=cut, group=cut))+
  geom_histogram()+
  facet_grid(.~cut) + 
  coord_flip()` or maybe `ggplot(data = diamonds, aes(price, fill=cut, group=cut))+
  geom_density()+
  facet_grid(.~cut) + 
  coord_flip()`. You can remove `coord_flip` to change the axes. Or maybe in one plot? `ggplot(data = diamonds, aes(price, col=cut, group=cut))+
  geom_density()+
  coord_flip()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might be looking for a bar chart, rather than a histogram. Histograms are for visualizing the distribution of a dataset by frequency. In your case, you seem to be looking for the total price of all the diamonds in each cut category.

To get the y-axis to what you wish to do, you would use `scales::dollar` to format the labels within `scale_y_continuous`

```
library(tidyverse)
library(scales)

ggplot(data = diamonds, aes(x = cut, y = price))+
  geom_bar(stat = "summary", fun.y = "sum") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = dollar)
```

[image]